# Does PM2 in cluster mode spawn an equal amount of class instances when running?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, pm2

I'm wondering if running a node process in cluster mode also means I'm running multiple instances of classes and timeout loops. One of the most concerning instances of this is puppeteer, which goes to external websites to grab information and update our database.

I'm running this on a t2.medium on AWS. If I run my node app in cluster mode, will it blow up the CPU usage?

I, unfortunately, can't extensively test this myself. I don't have sufficient permissions in my slice of heaven, and if I use up all my CPU credits I can't do anything for the rest of the day haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, if you run your application in cluster mode, PM2 will use the Node.js [Cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to spawn one thread per instance. If you are launching one browser in each of instance, this can quickly add up and potentially "blow up the CPU" as you said put it.

You could limit the number of running instances by using the `-i` parameter ([docs](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/load-balancing/)):

**Example** (will limit the number of workers to 2):

```
pm2 start crawler.js -i 2
```

---

Keep in mind that your Node.js instances will more or less idle (assuming you are not doing any complex computations there) as the browsers are doing the actual work. It might be an option to use a library to handle a [pool of browsers](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) (disclaimer: I'm the author of the linked library). This will put the complexity of handling multiple browsers into your application, making it easier to estimate the memory/CPU usage of your application when testing and removing the "complexity layer" of the PM2 cluster mode.